# Wheels and $0\cdot x \neq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I recently found [this link](http://www2.math.su.se/reports/2001/11/) and is facinated by the structure but I am trying to wrap my head around it. I understand that we have in $A\times A$ that
$$(a,b)\equiv_S (x,y)$$
for a multiplicative closed subset of $S\subseteq A$, is true if there exists $s,z\in S$ such that $(sa,sb)=(zx,zy)$. As long as $0\notin S$ the relation is non-trivial. With the standard localization version of addition and multiplication. So far all is fine, let's focus on $\Bbb Z^\odot$ as an easy example. let $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ and $x,y\neq 0$. Then we have
$$(x,y)\cdot (0,1) = (x\cdot 0,y\cdot 1)=(0,y)$$
and for then we can find $y,1\in S$, with $S=\Bbb Z-\{0\}$
 and get $(0y,1y)=(0,y)$. Which I get to be the ordinary one, but I read that it is not the case and I am curious where my reasoning goes wrong here.

Is it so it is true in this special wheel? If so got an example where it isn't? If not where did my reasoning go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found the answer myself. The issue is that in $\Bbb Z\odot(\Bbb Z-\{0\})$ (Which denotes the wheel over $\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb Z-\{0\}$ as the multiplicative subset) can be shown to it not mattering as we have
$$\Bbb Z\odot(\Bbb Z-\{0\})\simeq \Bbb Q\cup\{0/0,1/0\}=\Bbb Q\cup\{\bot,\top\}$$
so we get the same. I did find this example.
$$\Bbb Z_6\odot\{1,5\}$$
where we have 
$$\frac{0}{1}\neq \frac{0}{2}$$
as multiplying either with $1,5$ does not make it equal to the other as an ordered pair. Ergo they are not equal as fractions in the wheel.

Comment: Yes and Ihave clearified it